# Php Hidden FIeld how to forward to next page from fetched data from database

Tags: php

1. page1.php (data fetched from database)
   i have to forward 2 field using hidden field after showing the data to   page2.php
2. page2.php get the hidden field and show on it then forward to page3.php

Comment: Hi! What have you tried in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

use PHP session:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['input1'] = $input1;
$_SESSION['input2'] = $input2;
$_SESSION['input3'] = $input3;
```

Page2:

```
<?php
session_start();

$value1 = $_SESSION['input1'];
//etc...
```